# missing operand at _@_ in expect shell script

Tags: shell, sh, sftp, expect

Hi I want to transfer files in a directory to a remote server through automated SFTP script. I tried below code. But it is not working.

```
#! /bin/bash
i=0
for file in *; do
    array[ $i ]="$file"
    (( i++ ))
done

expect <<EOF
spawn sftp user1@10.121.121.121
expect "user1@10.121.121.121's password:"
send "password\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /user/KBACS/test\n"
expect {
    "sftp>" {
        for {set j 0} {$j < $i} {incr j 1} {
            send "put ${array[j]}\n";
        }
        send "bye\n";
    }

    EOF
}
EOF
```

I am able to login to the remote server. After that it is giving error like this.

```
    sftp> cd /user/KBACS/test
    sftp> missing operand at _@_
    in expression " _@_< 8"
        (parsing expression " < 8")
        invoked from within
    "for {set j 0} { < 8} {incr j 1} {
                            send "put 20171108.log\n";
                    }"
        invoked from within
    "expect {
            "sftp>" {
                    for {set j 0} { < 8} {incr j 1} {
                            send "put 20171108.log\n";
                    }
                    send "bye\n";
            }

        EOF
    }"
```

Please help me with this or suggest any alternate solution for this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using "expect" <<EOF after "spawn sftp user1@10.121.121.121"

Comment: It's a quoting problem. `$i` is a shell variable. You want `$j` to be an expect variable. However, because you're using an unquoted heredoc to contain the expect code, `$j` is exanded by the shell (an empty string) **before** expect reads the code it's supposed to run. See the line after the first "invoked from within". There are lots of examples on here on SO about mixing expect code in a shell script: search around for them.

Comment: I suspect "20171108.log" is the element at index zero in the array.

Comment: Your initial loop isn't necessary: `array=( * )`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you set up ssh keys so you don't need to provide a password, then use sftp in batch mode

```
{ printf "put %s\n" *; echo bye; } | sftp -b - user@host
```

If that's not feasible, then you don't need to combine expect and bash: expect (and Tcl) can figure out which files are in the current dir: [`glob`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sftp user1@10.121.121.121
expect "user1@10.121.121.121's password:"
send "password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /user/KBACS/test\r"
expect "sftp>"
foreach filename [glob *] {
    put "$filename\r"
    expect "sftp>"
}
send "bye\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Hi I tried the solution using glob but its not recognizing the variable filename. it saying that "You must specify at least one path after a put command." Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you still using expect in a here document in a shell script? Show your code in an edit to your question.